# Error loading libpthread.so on Android

Tags: android, linux, android-ndk, pthreads, spotify

I'm using the android-NDK-r10 to compile my C++ code that wraps the functions of libspotify.

In my app, I include two libraries in `onCreate()` method of a class extending `Service` like this:

```
System.loadLibrary("spotify");
System.loadLibrary("spotifywrapper");
```

In my C++ code (compiled to "libspotifywrapper.so"), I include libpthread as usual:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string>
#include <api.h>
```

Compiling with ndk-build works, I'm not getting any errors.

When I start my android app, dalvik crashes with the following message:

> 09-26 08:18:18.941: E/dalvikvm(11820): dlopen("/data/app-lib/com.example.myApp-1/libspotify.so") failed: dlopen failed: could not load library "libpthread.so.0" needed by "libspotify.so"; caused by library "libpthread.so.0" not found

I copied [this](https://github.com/embeddedarm/linux-2.6.35.3-imx28/blob/master/cross-toolchain/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi/multi-libs/armv7-a/lib/libpthread-2.11.1.so) version of libpthread into `libs/armeabi/`, renamed it to `libpthread.so`, and included it like the two libs above. When I'm running the app, it then produces an error, that `libc.so.6` isn't found.
Afaik, the libc isn't included in Android, isn't it?

Asking Google, I read that libpthread is included in libc, but as Android uses Bionic, I don't know if libpthread is included in it.

The actual question is: How do I get rid of this error, that libpthread isn't found?
I think it can't be that difficult, and as compiling works fine, it could not be a bug in my code. Are my Android-devices (4.4.4 and 4.4.2) the reason?

I hope you can help me,
Lukas

Answer (score 4):

There is no libpthread.so on Android, all the pthread features are directly implemented by the C library.

Your libspotify.so was not compiled with an Android-compatible toolchain, you won't be able to load/use it on Android. Ask whoever provided you with it an Android-compatible version instead, i.e. one that was built with an NDK toolchain.

Comment: I used the official libspotify version for android arm, it should work. I also tried the armv7 release, but this doesn't work too.

Comment: It it depends on libpthread.so.0, a library that does not exist on Android, it's certainly not an official Android arm binary. It's probably one for embedded Linux/arm systems instead. Again, please check with your provider.

Answer (score 0):

You might already be aware of this but Spotify has released an Android SDK (currently in beta).

You can find more information about it here:
https://developer.spotify.com/news-stories/2014/06/25/announcing-new-spotify-android-sdk-beta/

Comment: Yes I know, but as it doesn't provide offline playlists, I can't use it. I hope offline playback gets implemented soon.